# How to use must_not with an empty JSON attribute with ElasticSearch + Grails?

Tags: grails, elasticsearch

I'm using Grails plugin to work with ElasticSearch over MySQL. I have a domain column mapped in my domain class as follows:

```
String updateHistoryJSON
(...)
static mapping = {
    updateHistoryJSON type: 'text', column: 'update_history'
}
```

In MySQL, this basically maps to a TEXT column, which purpose is to store JSON content.

So, in both DB and ElasticSearch index, I have 2 instances:
- instance 1 has updateHistoryJSON = '{"zip":null,"street":null,"name":null,"categories":[],"city":null}'
- instance 2 has updateHistoryJSON = '{}'

Now, what I need is an ElasticSearch query that returns only instance 2.

I've been doing a closure like this, using Groovy DSL:

```
{
    bool {
        must_not = term(updateHistoryJSON: "{}")
        minimum_should_match = 1
    }
}
```

And ElasticSearch seems to ignore it, it keeps bringing back both instances.

On the other hand, if I use a filter like "missing":{"field":"updateHistoryJSON"}, it gives back no documents. The same goes for "exists": {"field":"updateHistoryJSON"}.

Any idea about what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not sure about what was the problem, but at least I found a workaround.

Since the search based on updateHistoryJSON contents was not working, I decided to use a script to search based on updateHistoryJSON contents size, meaning, instead of looking for documents that had a non-empty JSON, I just look for documents which updateHistoryJSON size is greater than 2 ({} == size 2).

The closure I used is like this:

```
{script = {
    script = "doc['updateHistoryJSON'].size() > 2"
}
```